# Contact form 7 on Revolution Slider cannot send a message

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, revolution-slider

I embedded a contact form 7 on revolution slider version 5.2.6, I successfully added it but when I tried to send a message. There is no prompt occur and I didn't even receive a message. Please guide me through this. Thanks

Please refer to this link [jwt.hotwork.ag](http://jwt.hotwork.ag/#contact)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update contact form 7 like this:

You can change the location by putting a response message placeholder `[response]` inside the form. You can insert this `[response]` tag into any place of your choice.  You can use it multiple times in a form.  https://contactform7.com/locating-response-message-box-anywhere/

```
[response]

Your Name (required)
[text* your-name]

Subject
[text your-subject]

Your Message
[textarea your-message]

[response]

[submit "Send"]
```

Comment: There is a success prompt now but I didn't receive a message.

Comment: Try mail-tester. `https://www.mail-tester.com/`
Set the given email in the `To:` section of your contact form and send a message.

Comment: It doesn't work. They can only test emails with @mail-tester.com extension.. My email is jw.taniza@gmail.com and it prompts like this "Please send your message to a xxx@mail-tester.com address".

Comment: Thank you so much! It turned out that the email that I inputted in the To: section is missing 1 letter. Thanks!